# Hide/show element on click or mediaqueries

Tags: javascript, jquery

On mobile > hide content and add a display button, click on the button display the content.
On Dekstop > display content hide the button.

```
var trickvis = true;
if (trickvis) {
    $('.trick').show(); // Affiche
 } else {
    $('.trick').hide();
   console.log('HIDE THE TRICKS');
 }

function myFunction(x) {

 if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
   var trickvis = false; // Cache les tricks
   $('.bttest').show(); // Ajout du bouton

 } else {
   trickvis = true;
   $('.bttest').hide();
 }
}

$( ".bttest" ).click(function() {
 trickvis = true ;
});
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/gloreau/pen/XWbKzab

I tried using a true false option for the hide show and modifying the true false if mobile dekstop or if the button was clicked but this don't seems to work :(.

```
<article class="trick">
  loilul
</article>
<article class="trick">
  loilul
</article>
<article class="trick">
  loilul
</article>
<button class="bttest"  type="button">Show </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with css media queries without the need for any JS. Give a 'content' class to the 'content' DOM element and a 'display-button' class to the display button element, and use the css `visibility` property as follows. You may optionally use the `display` property as which ever is appropriate for you. With display, however, the values are either `block` or `none`, among others omitted for simplicity.

```
.content {
   visibility: hidden;
}
.display-button {
   visibility: visible;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .display-button {
      visibility: hidden;
   }
   .content  {
      visibility: visible;
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The reason your code is not behaving as required is because you are showing/hiding only the "show button" on screen size change, you're not doing anything on the content( class="trick" ). Hide/shown the content as well depending on the screen size.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    var trickvis = false; // Cache les tricks
    $('.trick').hide(); // Ajout du bouton
    $('.bttest').show();
  } 
  else {
    trickvis = true;
    $('.bttest').hide();
    $('.trick').show();
  }
}

$( ".bttest" ).click(function() {
  $('.trick').show(); // Affiche
});

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

```css
/* CSS a retirer */
.trick {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  margin:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="trick">
  loilul
</article>
<article class="trick">
  loilul
</article>
<article class="trick">
  loilul
</article>
<button class="bttest"  type="button">Show </button>
```

Comment: Thank you, It does solve the probem in some way ! 
If anyone can just comment on why my solution was not working, it could be great to learn a bit from my mistake :) .

Comment: please post your html too and I will give you correction on your solution. Generally, however, it's not efficient to do with JS what you would normally do in css, unless you have a reason to do so.

Comment: Thank you Addis I'm adding it.

Comment: @Warry, consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure of how to do this ?

Comment: Oh I have find it !